# Como adicionar o endereço ao infowindow gmaps v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Tenho uma coleção de pontos onde visualizo todos eles no mapa! gostaria de adicionar um infowindow  "balãozinho" a cada um deles informando o endereço por extenso de cada coordenada.

```
    function initialize() {


        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitudes, longitudes);

        var options = {
            zoom: 12,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), options);
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        var pontos = [];
        if (coord.length > 1) {
            var adress = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < coord.length; i++) {
                var location = coord[i].split(",");

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(location[0], location[1]),
                    map: map,

                })
            }
        }
  }
        initialize();
```

Comment: http://gmap3.net/en/catalog/10-overlays/infowindow-35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa de basicamente três passos. Primeiro, inicie as classes [`InfoWindow`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows) para o balão e [`Geocoder`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Geocoder) para buscar o endereço a partir das coordenadas:

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
```

E em seguida, dentro do seu laço `for`, adicione um *listener* para o `Marker` abrir esta `InfoWindow` com um `click` e seu conteúdo:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent("Carregando...");
    infoWindow.open(map, this);
});
```

E ainda dentro deste *listener*, logo depois de abrir a `InfoWindow`, inicie a chamada de [geocodificação reversa](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', function() {
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': infoWindow.position}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            infoWindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
        }
    });
});
```

Ou seja, assim que a `InfoWindow` for aberta (por isso usei outro *listener*, o **domready**) e com o conteúdo *"Carregando..."*, busquei o endereço a partir da coordenada e em seguida troquei o conteúdo para o endereço formatado que veio no resultado.

Comment: dentro do setContent(''); eu queria adicionar mais uma informação,só que essas informações estão dentro de um array e não consigo obter os valores que estão em cada array ,dentro dessa função google.maps.event.addListener ,não reconhece o i++ do laço for que se encontra acima da função.

Comment: Não entendi. Tem como colocar esse trecho de código em algum lugar, como no [pastebin](http://pastebin.com)?

Comment: Posso fazer outra postagem?

Comment: infoWindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address+'Dados:'
+dados[i]);//o índice i não esta funcionando.

Comment: Para cada marker do meu mapa eu tenho um conteudo do  
infoWindow.setContent diferente . Só q esses valores diferentes estao dentro de um array ou seja cada posicão é uma informacao utilizada no marker ex: marker1=dados[1];//So pra entender um pouco mais.